# Why does sea colour differ from place to place?

Tags: optics, color-charge

If you notice the colour of sea changes from place to place. At some places it is of blue or green and even different in beach. What must be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, **Reflected Sunlight** determines the color of the sea. Tropical islands have turquoise seas because the water absorbs blue and reflects the red in the sunlight. If you go diving, you will notice that the water become bluer the deeper you go. This is because only the blue light waves are able to penetrate deep waters. Sometimes when there is a storm at sea, the water can look even black. The dark storm skies leave no light for the water to reflect.

Other times, **Algae growths** are responsible for the various different water colors. In the Red Sea, there is an algae bloom that creates red of the water. Algae also creates the green hue of the Colorado River in the Marble Canyon during the spring. Other parts of the Colorado River have a red tone due to sediment in the water.

These are just a few of the different reasons why the sea has different colors in different place. Depending on location and conditions, the sea can take on a multitude of surprising colors.